# Calling WSE 2.0 webservice using WCF client

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, client, wse

I have a client application that I am trying to re factor.  It was actually called with some old Microsoft.Web.Services2 client.  But I am trying to adopt it to be called by a WCF client.

I think I did this before, but I can't seem to remember how to do it successfully.

Basically they set up a Client Service Proxy.  From there they edit the header to add a timestamp of sorts, and a username token. They also set up a custom endpoint pulled from a configuration file.

```
 proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;
 proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(oUsrNmToken);
 proxy.Url = config.getAttribute("serviceEndPoint");
```

I am trying to recreate that behavior using a modern WCF client.

I am exploring the channel and endpoint properties of the client.  If you guys have any advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: please publish here the final request that the current client is sending (you can use Fiddler to see it).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't necessarily watch the traffic using Fidler.  Pretty sure I can't install that in our environment.  But this is more of a theoretical question as well.  I am pretty close to just giving up and using old fashioned Web references instead of WCF referrences.  I want to stay as current as possible.

Comment: I've seen cases where a WSE2 setting had an exact WCF matching binding, and cases where it required WCF extensibility, so there is no definitive answer. Some of the challenges is that WSE2 uses a WS-Addressing version which WCF does not support, it allowes a UsernameToken with nonce and digect, and also that it allowed low level customization of what exactly is signed that WCF does not.

Comment: I might just save myself the headache and go back to regular web references.  It might not be new and cool, but that is ok as well.